# Set combobox display text to a property of ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have the following collection which i would like to bind to a combobox:

```
public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Values
{ get; set; }

public class Parameter
{
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind the display text of the combobox to the Text property of the Parameter class, I've tried the following ways below but all to no avail:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Parameter.Text"
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Parameter\Text"
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
```

When I try the 3 methods above the [assembly name].Parameter is displayed in the combobox for each parameter.

The 2 methods above don't display anything in the combobox

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Path=Text}"
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Path=Values.Text}"
```

And this one takes the text of the first parameter,splits it into characters and displays each character as a **seperate** item in the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Path=Values/Text}"
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is the complete XAML code as requested

```
<ListBox BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemParams}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding ElementName=cmbColors, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Width="150" Name="cmbColors" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2, 1" Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**Params class:**

```
public class Params
{
    public Params(String name, ObservableCollection<Parameter> values)
    {
        Name = name;
        Values = values;
    }

    public String Name
    { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Values
    { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to simply remove the combobox item template or set `Text="{Binding Text}"`

```
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="2, 1" Text="{Binding}"/> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct formulation is one of those you already mention:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Text"
```

Please check again, and if it does not work post the XAML that you have verbatim.

Comment: I've posted the complete XAML hopes that helps identify the problem.At the moment the solution you've suggested doesn't work

Comment: @Deni: What you posted is not what I suggested though :) Please take a moment to edit, test, and then post the edited code if it does not work.

Comment: I've updated the question and tested the code again.Once again if i get the [assembly name].Parameter repeatedly displayed in the combobox

Comment: @Deni: What does the `{Binding ItemParams}` on the `ListBox` resolve to? That's what the binding engine expects to find `Values` on.

Answer (score 4):

You can do directly :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" />
```

For WPF every element of the ComboBox (ComboBoxItem) is a of type **T**, thus it will look for public properties on the **T**, this why just putting **Text** will work.