# Issue Populating ComboBox inside of ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, combobox

I was hoping someone can help me figure this issue out. The combox seems to only list an item as individual characters when the binding source only has one value. If it is two or more, it lists the items properly.

Here's are two links with people experiencing similar issues. 
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257778/set-combobox-display-text-to-a-property-of-observablecollectiont)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089843/populating-combobox-inside-listview-in-wpf)

```
<DataTemplate>
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 'Clusters'}" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding Path='TargetCluster', Mode=TwoWay}"
   Width="145"
/>
```

Here's the item source

```
$vCenters = @()
        Foreach ($vCenter in $VDIEnvironments) {
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetCluster -Value (
                 $clusters | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
              )[0].Name -Force
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Clusters -Value $(
                 $clusters | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
              ).Name -Force
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetDatastore -Value $(
                 $datastores | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name | Sort-Object -Descending FreeSpaceMB
              )[0].Name -Force
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Datastores -Value $(
                 $datastores | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
              ).Name -Force 
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TargetPortgroup -Value (
                 $portgroups | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name | Sort-Object -Descending NumPorts
              )[0].Name -Force
           $vCenter | 
              Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Portgroups -Value $(
                 $portgroups | ? VCName -like $vCenter.Name
              ).Name -Force

           $vCenters += $vCenter
        }
```

Filling the datagridvie

```
            $SelectedVCenters = $VCenters | 
               Where-Object Env -like $WPFboxEnvironment.Text | 
               Where-Object Datastores -ne $Null
            $SelectedVCenters | ForEach-Object {
               $WPFboxSrcVCenter.Items.Add($_.Name)
               $WPFlistTgtVCenters.Items.Add($_)
               $WPFlistTgtVCenters.SelectedItems.Add($_)
            }
```

Comment: This normally happens when you bind an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to a `string`. The `ItemsControl` usually accesses the collection bound to the `ItemsSource` by index, because it has to create a container for each data item ([`ItemContainerGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator?view=netframework-4.8)) in order to render the data as a `Visual` object. Since `string` implements an indexer like `public char this[int index] { get; }`, it is accessible by index like a collection or an array.

Comment: Now, when binding a `string` to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, the internal `ItemContainerGenerator` treats the `string` value like a collection and accesses it by index. Because of the indexer, the `string` will return its underlying characters.

Comment: Make sure you are always binding to a collection of `string`, but never to a `string` directly to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I somewhat understand. Do you mind giving me an example. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Here's the link to the whole script https://pastebin.com/7A6yzLzC

Comment: I tried to explain it with some more detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. My colleague and I ended up adding an empty cluster to all vCenters to remedy the issue. Not the best solution but it works and solve two problems that we had.

```
$clusters = Get-Cluster | Select-Object Name, Uid

$clusters | ForEach-Object {
   $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name VCName -Value $_.Uid.split('@')[1].split(':')[0]
}

$uniqueVCs = $clusters | select VCName | sort VCName -Unique

foreach ($VC in $uniqueVCs) {
   $clusterplaceholder = [pscustomobject]@{
      'Name'   = "Select a cluster"
      'Uid'    = " "
      'VCName' = $VC.VCName
   }
   $clusters += $clusterplaceholder
}

$clusters = $clusters | sort VCName, Uid
```

Answer (score -1):

This normally happens when you bind an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to a `string`. The `ItemsControl` internally accesses a copy of the collection bound to the `ItemsSource` by index, because it has to create a container for each data item ([`ItemContainerGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator?view=netframework-4.8)) in order to render the data as a `Visual` object.
Since `string` implements an indexer like

`public char this[int index] { get; }`

, it is accessible by index like a collection or an array.

Now, when binding a `string` to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, the `string` is copied to the `ItemsControl.Items` collection and passed on to the internal `ItemContainerGenerator`, which is responsible for the creation of the visual items that are finally rendered as a visual representation of the data. This `ItemContainerGenerator` is treats the `string` value like a collection (since `string` implements `IEnumerable`) and accesses it by index. Because of the implemented indexer, the `string` will return its underlying characters and then the generator creates a container for each. This is why the `string` looks split up.

Make sure you are always binding to a collection of `string`, but never to a `string` directly to avoid this behavior.

**The view model that exposes the string value and a collection of strings for binding**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string stringValue;
    public string StringValue
    {
      get => this.stringValue;
      set
      {
        this.stringValue= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> stringValues;
    public ObservableCollection<string> StringValues
    {
      get => this.stringValues;
      set
      {
        this.stringValues= value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml where the `DataContext` is the `ViewModel` class**

```
<!-- This ComboBox will display the single characters of the string value (each item is a character)-->
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding StringValue}" />

<!-- This ComboBox will display the strings of the StringValues collection (each item is a complete string) -->
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding StringValues}" />
```

The displayed items of a `ComboBox` (or `ItemsControl` in general) are actually containers. A container is the visual representation of the data and is complex like a `UserControl`. The container has `Border`, `Background`, `Padding`, `Margin` etc. It's a `Visual` that is composed of other `Visuals` (or controls). The `string` alone cannot be rendered like this (having a font, font color, background, etc).

Therefore the `ItemsControl` must create a visual container for each data object.
This is done by the  `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` which actually uses the `ItemContainerGenerator` to accomplish this. So, internally the `ComboBox` (or the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`) accesses the bound collection of `ItemsControl.Items` in order to create the container like this:

```
IItemContainerGenerator generator = this.ItemContainerGenerator;    
GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(0);

using (generator.StartAt(position, GeneratorDirection.Forward, true))    
{    
    DependencyObject container = generator.GenerateNext();    
    generator.PrepareItemContainer(container);    
}
```

As you can see the generator accesses the items by index. Under the hood the generator accesses a copy of `ItemsControl.Items` (`ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsInternal`) to retrieve the data that should be hosted by the container. This somehow (inside the generator) looks like:

```
object item = ItemsInternal[position];
```

Since `string` implements an indexer you can access a `string` also like an array:

```
var someText = "A String";
char firstCharacter = someText[0]; // References 'A' from "A String"
```

So when looking at the container generator code from above you now can now understand the effect the lines

```
GeneratorPosition position = generator.GeneratorPositionFromIndex(0);
```

and

```
generator.StartAt(position, GeneratorDirection.Forward, true)
```

have on a `string` where position is the actual item index: it retrieves character by character to map them to a container.

This is a simplified explanation of how the `ItemsControl` handles the source collection.

Comment: This is because string explicitly implements non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, and the enumerator will return the characters. That’s the declared type of ItemsSource. It’ll happily take enumerators without indexers, for example LINQ queries.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, that's right. Because `string` implements `IEnumerable`, it is assignable to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. But the actual enumeration by the `Generator` is not done by calling `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`. It's done by explicitly using the indexer, which is not part of the interface. For all collections (the index based), `IEnumerator` is implemented to use the indexer. For special collections like `LinkedList` it uses a different approach.

Comment: I just wrote a class that implements `IList<char>` and bound an instance to ListView.ItemsSource. In the debugger, it hits non-generic GetEnumerator(). It never hits the indexer. I don't know of a reasonably convenient way to put a breakpoint in String's indexer. How did you conclude that it's using the indexer belonging to ItemsSource?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I checked the source code of `ItemContainerGenerator`. Let me give you the link and show you the actual snippet. Please wait...

Comment: From what I can see in the debugger here, it looks like `Items` is an `ItemsCollection` containing a copy of whatever came out of the enumerator from `ItemsSource.GetEnumerator()`. Then they index the `ItemsCollection`; that's right there in the code in your answer already. It doesn't make sense to me for ItemsControl to have a whole different way of interacting with ItemsSource depending on whether there's an indexer or not. Much easier to grab a copy, stuff it in Items, and use that. Of course, just because it doesn't make sense to me doesn't mean they didn't do it that way.

Comment: @EdPlunkett This is from the `Generator.GenerateNext`method: `IList items = _factory.ItemsInternal;` where `_factory` is the `ItemContainerGenerator`. Then it accesses the items collection like: `object item = items[itemIndex];`

Comment: Items isn't ItemsSource.

Comment: [The source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemContainerGenerator.cs,93ffcecf086fd8a2)

Comment: No `ItemsSource` is mirrored to the `Items` property which maps to `ItemsContainerGnerator.ItemsInternal`.

Comment: The copying from ``ItemsSource` to `Items` will surely invoke the `GetEnumerator` member. I checked it. But the actual generation of the visual containers is done by accessing the indexer.

Comment: You are wrong. ItemsCollection is a collection object which contains a copy of the items in ItemsSource. Interesting theory, good detective work putting it together. But wrong. The indexer of Items is not the indexer of ItemsSource. The indexer of ItemsSource is never called. Not ever. Yes, ***the copying from ItemsSource to Items***. Copying. The indexer of `String` is never called. ItemsCollection is a collection of the chars found in that string, and *its* indexer is called.

Comment: I am sorry. Please read my last comment. `ItemsControl` copies the `ItemsSource` via a PropertyChangedCallback delegat called `OnItemsSourceChanged`. This uses `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView` on the `ItemsSource`. `Items is accessed by the `ItemContainerGenerator` which uses a copy to populate `InternalItems` to track realization of item containers. I am serious.

Comment: You claimed the indexer of String is called. It is not called. GetEnumerator() is called. Please correct your otherwise accurate and useful answer.

Comment: When the `ItemsSource` is a `string` the `items[itemIndex]` will be equal to `string.Char[itemIndex]`.

Comment: The line `object item = _factory.items[itemIndex]` is the line where each character is extracted and mapped to a container.

Comment: It calls GetEnumerator() on the String, obtaining an enumeration of the characters in the string. That is the answer to the question. The digression about indexers is, at best, an irrelevant discussion of the possible internals of some enumerators, a matter very far removed from the behavior of ItemsControl.

Comment: The poor kid asking the question does not need to worry about indexers or item container generators to understand what went wrong. He needs to understand that String is a collection of characters, and he could loop through it in a foreach if he wanted to, and that's what he's seeing in his UI. Then he needs to understand what to do to make his ItemsSource (`$vCenters?`) a collection of strings instead of a single string. I misspoke above; that last point is really the answer to the question. Sadly, I don't know PowerShell well enough to help.

Comment: I think I answered it. The first part of the answer explains that the string is enumerated by index in order to create the actual visual items: a container for each character. He asked for an example and I extended the answer with an example and then added some raw details. My intend was not to bring up concrete details on how the generator works. It was just you telling me I am a fine detective with an interesting theory but totally wrong. I needed to proof that I am right. Telling a beginner that `ItemsSource` is the operational target seems a reasonable abstraction level to me.